# Get All Attributes from an xml Element

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a function which returns me various Element attributes.
At this case I need to take ALL the attributes from a given Element
I manage to read the proper Element, and use the following code:

```
If XMLReader.HasAttributes Then
 For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In XmlNodeType.Attribute
  retVal = Attribute.Name + "+" + Attribute.Value
 Next
End If
```

Which obvious is not the right one because it throws me an error before I start using it 
`Expression is of type 'System.Xml.XmlNodeType', which is not a collection type`
Is there anyone show me the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it has an `Attributes` property which is a collection.

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
xmldoc.Load("path to file")
Dim concatValue As String = ""
For Each atr As XmlAttribute In xmldoc.DocumentElement.Attributes
  concatValue &= atr.Name & "+" & atr.Value
Next
```

Comment: Basically You're right... with an additional parameter... 
`For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In ElementControl.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(5).ChildNodes(2).ChildNodes(Attributes(1) - 1).Attributes
retVal = Attribute.Name + "+" + Attribute.Value
Next`
Attibute(1) is the number of node coming from the code, and that is because there are 500 child node here.
The other ChildNodes are the previous nodes until we come to the one we're interested... Thank you very much your answer was very good and point it exactly on my mistake I have... Thank you once again